# finding closest value in vector produces unexpected result

Tags: r

I am using this code (taken from [here](http://adomingues.github.io/2015/09/24/finding-closest-element-to-a-number-in-a-list/)):

```
values <- seq(0, 100, 5)
value <- 91

which(abs(values - value) == min(abs(values - value)))
```

It should produce 90 but returns 19?! Any idea why? Thanks!

Comment: `which()` returns the position index. Use `values[which(abs(values - value) == min(abs(values - value)))]` to return the actual value.

Comment: It's correct. It is the 19th value of your `values` vector.

Comment: Maybe also try `which.min` like `values[which.min(abs(values - value))]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code returns the position, you need to use it to get the actual value from `values`.

```
values[which(abs(values - value) == min(abs(values - value)))]
#[1] 90
```

Or with a temporary variable.

```
tmp <- abs(values - value) 
values[which(tmp == min(tmp))]
```

Answer (score 1):

`which` will give the `TRUE` indices of a logical object, and those can then be used to subset the vector to get the value. So either you use:

```
values[which(abs(values - value) == min(abs(values - value)))]
#[1] 90
```

where `which` could also be removed

```
values[abs(values - value) == min(abs(values - value))]
#[1] 90
```

In case you want only the first hit `which.min` could be used.

```
values[which.min(abs(values - value))]
#[1] 90
```

Also `findInterval` could be an option in case *values* is sorted and one result per *value* is wanted. This uses binary search and could be faster in case many nearest values are searched. In case *values* in not sorted it needs to be sorted for this method.

```
values[findInterval(value, values[-1] - diff(values)/2) + 1]
#[1] 90
```